# SQL Query to merge records

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I have an EMPLOYEE table in SQL Server Database with the below columns and data

[image]

I want to merge the 1st , 2nd and 3rd records (**ORDERED BY START_DATE**) as they are just extensions and produce the following output as

[image]

As you can see, I have merged the first 3 records and took the START_DATE from the 1st row and end the END_DATE from the 3rd row

I need a SQL query to create this output, which will merge consecutive records (time based) for an employee_id if their employee_types are the same.

Comment: Why the three different database systems which all have different SQL dialects? Or does the solution needs to work in MySQL, SQL Server and Oracle database?

Comment: Also SQL is by definition **orderless**. Meaning definitions like "first 3 records", "first record", "second record", "third record" are also **meaningsless**.. Do you have a column on which we can indentify the order by? Like a autoincrementing id or datetime columns which updates when insering/updateing

Comment: Also i advice you to convert the start_date and end_date data into a DATETIME database.

Comment: The reason i tagged MySQL, SQL Server and Oracle is because we need to have a solution for all the 3 DBs. Agreed. I will tag it one of them. Regarding orderless, the order that I am trying to establish is through START_DATE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem, but with date ranges.  The most general solution is to assume that there might be gaps between the rows (although your data does not have this).

You can solve this be finding out where the "periods of constancy" begin.  In this case, `lag()` is your friend.  Then when you find where they begin, a cumulative sum identifies the groups and aggregation solves the problem:

```
select employee_id, employee_type,
       min(start_date), max(end_date)
from (select e.*,
             sum(case when start_date = dateadd(day, 1, prev_end_date) then 1 else 0 end) over
                 (partition by employee_id, employee_type) as grp
      from (select e.*,
                   lag(end_date) over (partition by employee_id, employee_type order by start_date) as prev_end_date
            from employee e
           ) e
     ) e
group by employee_id, employee_type, grp;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for introducing me to this design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

This should help, although you should really tag a the target database, and avoid tagging randomly.

For SQL Server & MySQL

```
SELECT 
    employee_id
,   employee_type 
,   MIN(start_date) start_date
,   MAX(end_date) end_date
FROM 
    EMPLOYEE 
GROUP BY 
    employee_id
,   employee_type 
,   YEAR(end_date)
ORDER BY start_date
```

and For Oracle

```
SELECT 
    employee_id
,   employee_type 
,   MIN(start_date) start_date
,   MAX(end_date) end_date
FROM 
    EMPLOYEE 
GROUP BY 
    employee_id
,   employee_type 
,   extract(year from end_date)
ORDER BY start_date
```

Demos :

[SQL Server](https://rextester.com/IBY75158)

[Oracle](https://rextester.com/TEKQC45108)

[MySQL](https://rextester.com/FXTT16956)

Comment: Will likely not work like expected the date format looks like to be a invalid MySQL date format string.. This will work on DATETIME datatype or on CHAR|VARCHAR datatypes which follow valid MySQL dataformats like `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: This answer wont work because it will combine the last record also. I dont want the last record to be merged. Only consecutive records which share the same "employee type" should be merged

Comment: @RaymondNijland I'm with you, but since it's a picture from Excel, I assumed that the actual data is datetime, if not, then the OP needs to convert it.

Comment: @Senthil I have updated my answer, tried to cover all three dbmses since you want something that work on all three of them.

Comment: @iSR5, thanks for your answer, but if all the end dates are in the same year, then the query doesnt work out.

Comment: @Senthil would you please provide a sample data?, as the query will give you the highest end_date despite the duplicates year.

Answer (score 0):

The following query helped to solve the problem

```
SELECT employee_id,
       employee_type,
       MIN(start_date) ,
       MAX(end_date) 
FROM   (SELECT *,
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id ORDER BY start_date),
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id, employee_type ORDER BY start_date),
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id ORDER BY start_date) - 
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id, employee_type ORDER BY start_date) AS Grp
         FROM   employee) T
GROUP  BY employee_id,
       employee_type,
          Grp
ORDER  BY 3 asc
```